# Do programs on an SSD with Windows run faster than they would on a second non-windows SSD?

Tags: windows, ssd, performance

I just added a second SSD to my system and I'm thinking about moving most of my programs to that SSD. Will this decrease performance for these programs as they're not on the same SSD as Windows anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving (uninstalling and re-installing) the programs to a second disk should not decrease the performance. (assuming the disks are same speed and connected on a same-speed bus). If it was magnetic HDD disks it might even increase your performance but I doubt it would have any noticeable effect at all on an SSD.